# How to implement ThreadX's ppp_byte_send for NXP MIMXRT1040-EVK

Tags: embedded, uart, nxp-microcontroller, threadx

I'm working on getting PPPoS working in ThreadX on an MIMXRT1040-EVK. However, I'm facing an obstacle related to the sending of PPP data over UART.

In ThreadX's `nx_ppp_create` function one of the parameters is `ppp_byte_send`, which should send 1 byte over the serial interface to the modem (Quectel EG800Q). To do this I use `LPUART_WriteBlocking` from NXP's SDK. However, the modem doesn't respond when using this mechanism. Here's the implementation:

```
void ppp_byte_send(UCHAR byte)
{
    LPUART_WriteBlocking(MODEM_REG_BASE, byte, 1);
}
```

I've determined the sequence of bytes being sent in the first message, and when sending these in a single call to `LPUART_WriteBlocking` it works:

```
void ppp_byte_send(UCHAR byte)
{
    uint8_t cmd[] = { 0x7E, 0xFF, 0x7D, 0x23, 0xC0, 0x21, 0x7D, 0x21, 0xC3, 0x7D, 0x20, 0x7D, 0x28, 0x7D, 0x21, 0x7D, 0x24, 0x7D, 0x25, 0xDC, 0xF1, 0xB7, 0x7E };
    LPUART_WriteBlocking(MODEM_REG_BASE, cmd, sizeof(cmd));
}
```

I also tried sending the bytes listed above one by one in a loop, but that also doesn't work.

I'm wondering if there's a different way I should go about implementing the `ppp_byte_send` function that ThreadX requires? From my testing it seems that sending byte by byte like this is too slow for the modem.

For reference:

- the UART speed is 115200bps
- I know my MCU+modem combo works as I've gotten it working in both Zephyr and FreeRTOS+LwIP

Thanks

Comment: Just to verify my suspicion another way, I modified NX_PPP to have a new member: `void (*nx_ppp_bytes_send)(UCHAR* bytes, UINT len); `

and `_nx_ppp_packet_transmit`: instead of calling `nx_ppp_byte_send` for each byte that needs to be sent, it instead put them into a buffer and calls `nx_ppp_bytes_send` once. When doing this the modem also responds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll blame this on it being Friday afternoon. LPUART_WriteBlocking takes in a pointer to the data, not a single byte, so it should be:

```
void ppp_byte_send(UCHAR byte)
{
    LPUART_WriteBlocking(MODEM_REG_BASE, &byte, 1);
}
```

Now it works...!

Comment: In what world would your compiler not have issued an error for that?

Comment: I'm not able to check atm, but it's probably among the warnings the compiler outputs. There are quite a few as I'm doing some prototyping for work, so I didn't notice the additional one popping up. Also, warnings as errors is not enabled.